# Use telegram bot WebApp integration in groups

Tags: web-applications, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I followed telegram bot api documentation for the new feature of web application in telegram bots, but I managed to get it working only in private chats with the bot.

Can it be also used in groups? If no, is it planned for future updates?

I didn't found anything about groups in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You may put a [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#direct-link-web-apps) inside a text message that will open Web App on click. It works as expected and supports both channels and groups. [Register a WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172640/3160483) first.

[image] [image]

```
https://t.me/botusername/appname
https://t.me/botusername/appname?startapp=command
```

If you want to use [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) with the `web_app` type, it will work only in private chats:

> Description of the Web App that will be launched when the user presses the button. The Web App will be able to send an arbitrary message on behalf of the user using the method answerWebAppQuery.  *Available only in private chats between a user and the bot.*

Comment: how did you put the direct link to the webapp? I know how to put the link to the bot, but not to the webapp of the bot (I assume it's not the same as just the link to the webapp (unbinded to telegram))

Comment: link to the bot + `/appname`. You may read more at the section [Direct Link Mini Apps](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#implementing-mini-apps), subsection [Direct Link Mini Apps](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#direct-link-mini-apps)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible now. WebApp working only in private chat with bot.

Answer (score -1):

So, for in 2023 you can do it.

Comment: Is it? The [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) docs says it's "Available only in private chats between a user and the bot."

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#inline-mode-mini-apps