# How can I get the 'appname' to build t.me URL for launching Telegram Web App for Bots

Tags: web-applications, telegram

On the [documentation page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#direct-link-web-apps) of Telegram's Web Apps we can read this:

> ###### Direct Link Web Apps
>
> You can use direct links to open a Web App directly in the current
> chat. If a non-empty startapp parameter is included in the link, it
> will be passed to the Web App in the start_param field and in the GET
> parameter tgWebAppStartParam.
>
> In this mode, Web Apps can use the chat_type and chat_instance
> parameters to keep track of the current chat context. This introduces
> support for concurrent and shared usage by multiple chat members – to
> create live whiteboards, group orders, multiplayer games and similar
> apps.
>
> Web Apps opened from a direct link have no access to the chat – they
> can't read messages or send new ones on behalf of the user. To send
> messages, the user must be redirected to inline mode and actively pick
> a result.
>
> ###### Examples
>
> - ```
>   https://t.me/botusername/appname
>   ```
> - ```
>   https://t.me/botusername/appname?startapp=command
>   ```

So, where we can get the appname? Does anybody can explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to create a `t.me` link to automatically open the [WebApp](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps), you'll need to register the app with the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather):

1. Use the `/newapp` command
2. Fill in all the requested data, the username of the bot it's linked to, a title, description, photo and demo GIF
3. Eventually, BotFather will ask for the **short name**:

   > Good! Now please choose a short name for your web app: 3-30 characters, `a-zA-Z0-9_`. **This short name will be used in URLs like `t.me/some_bot/myapp` and serve as a unique identifier for your web app**.
4. After passing the short name, BotFather will send you an example link to open the WebApp:

   > You can now use `testapp` as the short_name parameter value in Bot API. Your web app link is `t.me/some_bot/testapp`. Open it to start developing your web app!

Comment: Web App for bot is not such application. It's web application coded in React for example. How can I connect this app with App configuration?

Comment: Yep, you're right, please see my edit. I've created a WebApp to test this and it automatically opens the app!

Comment: I banged my head trying to implement this in node. BotFather is the cure to all problems.